# Rest Cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, rest, maven, gwt, resty-gwt

I'm trying to write my Rest Interface with restygwt therefore I inherit

```
<inherits name='org.fusesource.restygwt.RestyGWT' />
```

and also added the dependency into my pom file.

```
import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;

import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.MethodCallback;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.RestService;

@Path("/user")
public interface UserRestService extends RestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void getUsers(MethodCallback<List<User>> callback);
}
```

All my Annotations cannot be resolved to a type. Is there also another library necessary or what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JAX-RS 2.0 annotations

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added the JAX-RS dependency, know it works fine.

```
    <!-- JAX-RS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add these jars to your project.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```